# Multiply/divide 2.0

Tags: assembly, masm

I had posted recently about a multiply divide menu i have been working on, (Thanks again for the input everyone!), but I recently scrapped that code and with the help of a friend with assembly language experience i know at work I now have something i think is a bit closer to an end product. But when I finally got home to put it together I realized he had been showing my some NASM he knew which doesn't quite work with the MASM! I've been going error by error trying to convert any bits that don't work, to their MASM equivalents using an online guide. But now I think I've hit a point where I could use some outside help. im getting a couple linker errors LNK2001 unresolved external symbol_WinMainCRTStartup and LNK1120 1 unresolved externals.

If someone could help me troubleshoot or if someone else's system can run this does it seem to work?

```
   TITLE mainmenu

; Description: This program presents a menu that will prompt the user decide whether they wouldd like to multiply or divide. The programs reads the numbers in the range 1 to 100. If an invalid selection is made the program will close.
; Revision date: 4/29/2017
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc


.data

.code

main PROC

; Messages


msg1 db 10,'-Mulitply or Divide Calculator-',10,0

lmsg1 equ $ - msg1

msg2 db 10,'Number 1: ',0

lmsg2 equ $ - msg2

msg3 db 'Number 2: ',0

lmsg3 equ $ - msg3

msg4 db '3. Multiply',10,0

lmsg4 equ $ - msg4

msg5 db '4. Divide',10,0

lmsg5 equ $ - msg5



msg6 db 'Operation: ',0

lmsg6 equ $ - msg6



msg7 db 10,'Result: ',0

lmsg7 equ $ - msg7

msg8 db 10,'Invalid Option',10,0

lmsg8 equ $ - msg8

nlinea db 10,10,0

lnlinea equ $ - nlinea

dw ?


; Spaces reserved for storing the values provided by the user.

opc BYTE ?

num1 byte ?

num2 byte ?

result word ?



_start:



; Print on screen the message 1



mov eax, 4

mov ebx, 1

mov ecx, OFFSET msg1

mov edx, lmsg1

int 80h



; Print on screen the message 2



mov eax, 4

mov ebx, 1

mov ecx,OFFSET msg2

mov edx, lmsg2

int 80h



; We get num1 value.



mov eax, 3

mov ebx, 0

mov ecx, OFFSET num1

mov edx, 2

int 80h



; Print on screen the message 3



mov eax, 4

mov ebx, 1

mov ecx, OFFSET msg3

mov edx, lmsg3

int 80h



; We get num2 value.



mov eax, 3

mov ebx, 0

mov ecx,  OFFSET num2

mov edx, 2

int 80h


; Print on screen the message 4



mov eax, 4

mov ebx, 1

mov ecx, OFFSET msg4

mov edx, lmsg4

int 80h



; Print on screen the message 5



mov eax, 4

mov ebx, 1

mov ecx, OFFSET msg5

mov edx, lmsg5

int 80h



; Print on screen the message 6



mov eax, 4

mov ebx, 1

mov ecx, OFFSET msg6

mov edx, lmsg6

int 80h



; We get the option selected.



mov ebx,0

mov ecx,  OFFSET opc

mov edx,2

mov eax,3

int 80h

mov ah, opc ; Move the selected option to the registry ah

sub ah, '0' ; Convert from ascii to decimal



; We compare the value entered by the user to know what operation to perform.



cmp ah, 1

cmp ah, 2


cmp ah, 3

je multiply

cmp ah, 4

je divide



; If the value entered by the user does not meet any of the above

; conditions then we show an error message and we close the program.



mov eax, 4

mov ebx, 1

mov ecx,  OFFSET msg8

mov edx, lmsg8

int 80h



main ENDP


; We keep the numbers in the registers al and bl



mov al, num1

mov bl, num2



; Convert from ascii to decimal



sub al, '0'

sub bl, '0'




; Print on screen the message 7


multiply PROC





; We store the numbers in registers al and bl



mov al, num1

mov bl, num2



; Convert from ascii to decimal



sub al, '0'

sub bl, '0'



; Multiply. AX = AL x BL



mul bl



; Conversion from decimal to ascii



add ax, '0'



; We move the result



mov result, ax



; Print on screen the message 7



mov eax, 4

mov ebx, 1

mov ecx, OFFSET msg7

mov edx, lmsg7

int 80h



; Print on screen the result



mov eax, 4

mov ebx, 1

mov result, ax

mov edx, 1

int 80h



; We end the program




multiply ENDP



divide PROC





; We store the numbers in registers ax and bx



mov al, num1

mov bl, num2

mov dx, 0

mov ah, 0



; Convert from ascii to decimall



sub al, '0'

sub bl, '0'



; Division. AL = AX / BX



div bl



; Conversion from decimal to ascii



add ax, '0'



; We move the result



mov result, ax



; Print on screen the message 7



mov eax, 4

mov ebx, 1

mov ecx, OFFSET msg7

mov edx, lmsg7

int 80h



; Print on screen the result



mov eax, 4

mov ebx, 1

mov ecx, OFFSET result

mov edx, 1

int 80h



; We end the program



divide ENDP







; Print on screen two new lines



mov eax, 4

mov ebx, 1

mov ecx, OFFSET nlinea

mov edx, lnlinea

int 80h



; End the program



mov eax, 1

mov ebx, 0

int 80h

end
```

Comment: `int 80h` is a Linux system call, and won't work on Windows. Your friend created a Linux specific program that will not run on Windows even if you could get it to assemble and link to an executable.

Comment: If you have `irvine32.inc` it has the ability to print to the display and read from the keyboard. You can find information on using Irvine library here: http://kipirvine.com/asm/ . It also has many examples in the tutorials that can be used as a basis for a program.

Comment: oh well glad to know it wasn't something I did! Thanks for the resources.